'Could not read source map errors' for node modules
Launch.json pic
While I was trying to figure out how to incorporate React into HTML, these errors appeared:
Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40jridgewell/gen-mapping/dist/gen-mapping.umd.js: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@jridgewell\gen-mapping\dist\gen-mapping.umd.js.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40jridgewell/sourcemap-codec/dist/sourcemap-codec.umd.js: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@jridgewell\sourcemap-codec\dist\sourcemap-codec.umd.js.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40jridgewell/set-array/dist/set-array.umd.js: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@jridgewell\set-array\dist\set-array.umd.js.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40jridgewell/resolve-uri/dist/resolve-uri.umd.js: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@jridgewell\resolve-uri\dist\resolve-uri.umd.js.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40ampproject/remapping/node_modules/%40jridgewell/gen-mapping/dist/gen-mapping.umd.js: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@ampproject\remapping\node_modules\@jridgewell\gen-mapping\dist\gen-mapping.umd.js.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/node_modules/%40ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.mjs: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\node_modules\@ampproject\remapping\dist\remapping.mjs.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/%40babel/babel-preset-env/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/esm/index.mjs: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\@babel\babel-preset-env\node_modules\babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3\esm\index.mjs.map'

Could not read source map for 
    file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Custom%20Scheduler/%40babel/babel-preset-env/node_modules/%40babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider/esm/index.browser.mjs: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
    'c:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\Custom Scheduler\@babel\babel-preset-env\node_modules\@babel\helper-define-polyfill-provider\esm\index.browser.mjs.map'

I tried the resolveSourceMapLocations solution, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work (I tried putting it inside the configs, outside the configs, used pwa-google).
How do I fix these errors?

Please don't add images of text. [Edit] your question to include the JSON as text, meaning, copy-paste it.
